# Where can I get a VS 2005 Report Server project template?

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, visual-studio-2005

Problem:

-- I have a VS 2005 Report Server project with many reports.

-- I moved it to a new computer with SQL Server 2008 and VS 2005 and 2010 installed.

-- I was able to port the 2005 Report Server over OK (it's still 2005 even though the server is 2008), but now I can't open up my old project in VS 2005.

As I understand it, it's because SQL Server 2005 is not installed, which would have installed the Report Server Project template in VS 2005. SQL Server 2008 uses a different type of report project template.

So my question is: is it possible to get this template from somewhere else, other than from SQL Server 2005? For example, the Visual Studio 2005 on my old computer has this template installed. Is it possible to export it in some way? Or can I download it from the web somewhere?

I really need to be able to open this project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so, you'd need to install the Visual Studio 2005 Business Intelligence Designer Studio (BIDS) that came on the SQL Server 2005 install.

If you're a masochist and you sound desperate enough, you can download [Report Builder 1.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155933.aspx) and use it to edit your reports. If you've watched the Harry Potter flicks, the 1.0 version of that app is a Dementor and prepare to have the joy sucked out of your life if you have to use the tool for very long. You can browse to your reporting server instance http://myserver/Reports/ (assuming default install) and there will be a Report Builder link there which runs a clickOnce non-install. MS does not supply a local install of the tool as they have with 2.0 and 3.0

Comment: LOL no I really have no desire to meet a dementor ... We are looking into setting up a virtual machine on which SQL 2005 can be installed. Thanks for confirming it's not otherwise possible, which was my suspicion.